# Adding sqrt to interpreter

Tags: racket

I'm trying to add sqrt function to my proffesor language in racket, here is the language:

```
;; ** The MUWAE interpreter

#lang pl 03

#| BNF for the MUWAE language:
     <MUWAE> ::= <num>
             | { + <MUWAE> <MUWAE> }
             | { - <MUWAE> <MUWAE> }
             | { * <MUWAE> <MUWAE> }
             | { / <MUWAE> <MUWAE> }
             | { sqrt <MUWAE>      }
             | { with { <id> <WAE> } <MUWAE> }
             | <id>
|#

;; MUWAE abstract syntax trees
(define-type MUWAE
  [Num  Number]
  [Add  MUWAE MUWAE]
  [Sub  MUWAE MUWAE]
  [Mul  MUWAE MUWAE]
  [Div  MUWAE MUWAE]
  [sqrt MUWAEE]
  [Id   Symbol]
  [With Symbol MUWAE MUWAE])

(: parse-sexpr : Sexpr -> MUWAE)
;; to convert s-expressions into MUWAEs
(define (parse-sexpr sexpr)
  (match sexpr
    [(number: n)    (Num n)]
    [(symbol: name) (Id name)]
    [(cons 'with more)
     (match sexpr
       [(list 'with (list (symbol: name) named) body)
        (With name (parse-sexpr named) (parse-sexpr body))]
       [else (error 'parse-sexpr "bad `with' syntax in ~s" sexpr)])]
    [(list '+ lhs rhs) (Add (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
    [(list '- lhs rhs) (Sub (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
    [(list '* lhs rhs) (Mul (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
    [(list '/ lhs rhs) (Div (parse-sexpr lhs) (parse-sexpr rhs))]
    [(list 'sqrt s) (sqrt (parse-sexpr s))]
    [else (error 'parse-sexpr "bad syntax in ~s" sexpr)]))

(: parse : String -> MUWAE)
;; parses a string containing a MUWAE expression to a MUWAE AST
(define (parse str)
  (parse-sexpr (string->sexpr str)))

#| Formal specs for `subst':
   (`N' is a <num>, `E1', `E2' are <MUWAE>s, `x' is some <id>,
   `y' is a *different* <id>)
      N[v/x]                = N
      {+ E1 E2}[v/x]        = {+ E1[v/x] E2[v/x]}
      {- E1 E2}[v/x]        = {- E1[v/x] E2[v/x]}
      {* E1 E2}[v/x]        = {* E1[v/x] E2[v/x]}
      {/ E1 E2}[v/x]        = {/ E1[v/x] E2[v/x]}
      y[v/x]                = y
      x[v/x]                = v
      {with {y E1} E2}[v/x] = {with {y E1[v/x]} E2[v/x]}
      {with {x E1} E2}[v/x] = {with {x E1[v/x]} E2}
|#

(: subst : MUWAE Symbol MUWAE -> MUWAE)
;; substitutes the second argument with the third argument in the
;; first argument, as per the rules of substitution; the resulting
;; expression contains no free instances of the second argument
(define (subst expr from to)
  (cases expr
    [(Num n) expr]
    [(Add l r) (Add (subst l from to) (subst r from to))]
    [(Sub l r) (Sub (subst l from to) (subst r from to))]
    [(Mul l r) (Mul (subst l from to) (subst r from to))]
    [(Div l r) (Div (subst l from to) (subst r from to))]
    [(sqrt s) (sqrt (subst l from to))]
    [(Id name) (if (eq? name from) to expr)]
    [(With bound-id named-expr bound-body)
     (With bound-id
           (subst named-expr from to)
           (if (eq? bound-id from)
             bound-body
             (subst bound-body from to)))]))

#| Formal specs for `eval':
     eval(N)         = N
     eval({+ E1 E2}) = eval(E1) + eval(E2)
     eval({- E1 E2}) = eval(E1) - eval(E2)
     eval({* E1 E2}) = eval(E1) * eval(E2)
     eval({/ E1 E2}) = eval(E1) / eval(E2)
     eval(id)        = error!
     eval({with {x E1} E2}) = eval(E2[eval(E1)/x])
|#

(: eval : MUWAE -> Number)
;; evaluates MUWAE expressions by reducing them to numbers
(define (eval expr)
  (cases expr
    [(Num n) n]
    [(Add l r) (+ (eval l) (eval r))]
    [(Sub l r) (- (eval l) (eval r))]
    [(Mul l r) (* (eval l) (eval r))]
    [(Div l r) (/ (eval l) (eval r))]
    [(sqrt s) (sqet (eval s))]
    [(With bound-id named-expr bound-body)
     (eval (subst bound-body
                  bound-id
                  (Num (eval named-expr))))]
    [(Id name) (error 'eval "free identifier: ~s" name)]))

(: run : String -> Number)
;; evaluate a MUWAE program contained in a string
(define (run str)
  (eval (parse str)))
```

But when i try to run my code i get:

> define-type: variant name is already bound in: sqrt

I added the sqrt function in my bnf stracture and added in all the eval, subst and sexper, but i have problem i guess in the stracture.

i guess that sqrt is a save word and in need to override the word, this is the way to do it so? there is another way?

what does error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying your program:

The problem is that the language `#lang pl 03` has a `sqrt` operator already.
The name is therefore already used; and when you try to give another meaning you get the error "variant name is already bound in: sqrt".

I think the simplest fix is to call your square root operator for `Sqrt` instead.